# SABR: implied vol formulas

Tags: sabr

I noticed that the approximate implied volatilities in [Hagan’s 2002 paper](https://github.com/ynouri/pysabr/blob/master/papers/Hagan%20-%20Managing%20Smile%20Risk%20-%202002.pdf) (see B69.a and BC9.c, please refer to the paper for the definition of the parameters):
[image]

are different from the formulas on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SABR_volatility_model) (under Asymptotic solution):

[image]
[image]

The wikipedia formulas are also different from [Hagan's 2014 paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264718376_Arbitrage-free_SABR): 
[image]

Does anybody know where these formulas on wikipedia come from? A reference would be nice.

The wiki page mentions F_mid, which can either be the geometric or the arithmetic average. How to decide which average to use? It seems that Hagan's paper uses the arithmetic average.

Thanks in advance!

Nele

Comment: Which formula on Wikipedia? Can you be specific?

Comment: @JaehyukChoi: i have updated my post. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I found at that the wiki formula's are in fact in Hagan's 2002 paper, in appendix C.